# How can i find the path of my file in my Java project file?

Tags: java, file, path

I put a file inside my Java project file and i want to read it but how can i find the path name with Java.

Here i put it in C driver but i just want to find path by just writing the name of file. Is there a function for it?

```
   FileInputStream fstream1 = new FileInputStream("C:/en-GB.dic");
```

Comment: I don't understand. First, you speak of a Java project, what IDE (eclipse?)? Second, Where is this project located? If your file is located in the root folder of where your program is run, then you can just put the name of the file in there... Is this, what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file is inside the jar file generated for your project (or in the classpath used by your project, generally), under the package `com.foo.bar`, you can load it using

```
SomeClassOfYourProject.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/foo/bar/en-GB.dic");
```

If it's not in the classpath, and you launch the application (using java.exe) from the directory `c:\baz`, and the file is under `c:\baz\boom\`, the you can load it using

```
new FileInputStream("boom/en-GB.dic");
```

Answer (score 0):

Place it in your classpath, If it is a web application `WEB-INF/classes/yourfile.ext`, if it is a standalone application place it in `bin` directory of your application (default class directory is bin).

Then you could read by using one of the following ways.

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("yourfile.ext");
```

Or

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/yourfile.ext");
```

You can read online for the differences between above two approaches.